# Getting Error using 'horzcat' Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation

To solve the equation using a full matrix It's worth noting that as N increases, the size of the full matrix A grows quickly. I am trying to find the largest number of points N in a sparse matrix and use the approach are as follw but it is giving me Error using 'horzcat' Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

N = 1000;
h=0.25

while true

```
main_diag = (2/h^2) * ones(N-1, 1);
sub_diag = (-1/h^2) * ones(N-2, 1);
A = spdiags([sub_diag, main_diag, sub_diag], [-1, 0, 1], N-1, N-1);

try
    full(A);
catch
    N = N - 1; % Reduce N if an error occurs
    continue;
end

break;
```

end

disp(['Largest N for a sparse matrix: ' num2str(N)]);

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solvable by simply debugging the code. You should do it yourself by putting breakpoints on the line that is throwing the error and analyzing the dimensions.

By doing so it is noticeable that in line `A = spdiags([sub_diag, main_diag, sub_diag], [-1, 0, 1], N-1, N-1);` you are trying to horizontally concatenate 3 vectos with different dimensions. In fact:

- **sub_diag** is of size 998x1
- **main_diag** is of size 999x1

hence they can't be concatenated.

(On a side note, the while true construct + exit condition in a catch try block is incredibly bad programming practice, try to restructure you code to avoid such a monstrosity)